# Add vue.js Component from Child to Parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Is there any way to render a vue.js component from a child component to on of its parents (maybe not the direct parent) like with slots but in the opposite direction?

**My use case:** In my root component I do have a `<router-view>` and a container for modals. from any child component of the router-view I would like to be able to add a child component to the modal wrapper.

Did I miss a feature of vue.js here or is there a even better practice to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't quite get the question, but if you use a global component you could simply re-use it across multiple elements and apply your own slot content to it in each.
So in that case you would register a global *AppModal* component with one or more slots and simply use it in your children where you need to.

Comment: Hmm, but if i want to have different modals which can be called from the the same view and maybe even from inside another modal, this does not seem to be so flexible like I want it to be. while researching this problem I tried to trigger the model by events ($emit  and v-on) but did not see any way to render content to the parent after receiving the event in the parent.

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Roy J answered a solution in the comments:

The solution is to use [Dynamic Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components) to create a "placeholder" component in the root component and switch its content by emiting [Custom Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events) in the child components.

Answer (score 1):

I guess I am late to the party, but here is my solution for coming generations (valid only if you use vue-router):

```
routes: [  
  path: '/dashboard',
  name: 'dashboard',
  component: DashboardIndex,
  children: [{
      path: 'popup',
      component: PopupPlaceholder,
      children: [{
          path: 'a',
          name: 'a',
          component: A,
      }, {
          path: 'b',
          name: 'b',
          component: B,
      }],
  }],
]
```